# Perl file I/O issue

Tags: html, perl

I'm developing a Perl script that's supposed to generate an HTML file from numerical values from other file. The idea is to read the file that has these values and then list them in a separate HTML file. The file that contains the numerical values is updated every a certain period of time, and those changes should be seen on the HTML.

Even though these values are correctly read (I've tested it) they are not printed in the HTML. Whats-more, the HTML tags are not even printed. This is the code I've written:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use IO::Handle;
use CGI qw(:standard);

print "Status: 200 OK", "\n";
print "Content-type: text/plain", "\n\n";

for(;;) {
    open (my $input_file, "<", "/path/to/input/file/input_file.txt") || die "Unable to open the file: $!";
    open (my $html_file, ">", "/path/to/html/file/index.html") || die "Unable to open the HTML file: $!";
    print $html_file "<html><head><title>title</title><META HTTP-QUIV='refresh' CONTENT='10'></head><body>";
    @lines = <$input_file>;
    foreach my $line (@lines) {
        print $html_file "<p>$line</p>";
    }
    print $html_file "</body></html>";
    sleep 1;
    close $input_file || die;
    close $html_file || die; 
}
```

The script only works in the first **for** iteration. What I mean is that the HTML tags and the numerical values are correctly printed in the output file. Then, from iteration 2 to N, the **file remains literally empty**. I can not see what I'm missing here. Why does it work in the first iteration but not in the following ones?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you load the CGI and IO::Handle modules, but make no use of them? Are they used in other bits of the program that you haven't shown us?

Comment: @Dave, I've used autoflush before deciding to open and close the file in the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `close` the file *before* the `sleep`. As it stands, the data is flushed to the file by the `close` and then immediately overwritten by the next `open`, and left empty for one second

You also need to write

```
close $html_file or die $!
```

as the code you have is equivalent to

```
close($html_file || die)
```

so your program will never die as long as `$html_file` is *true*

Comment: Yes, that was it. Now you works as expected. Thank you very much!